# Run windows form while running an XNA game

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently designing a RPG game which requires me to utilize an inventory system. Ideally, the user would press a key and make the the character's inventory window open.

example:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if ((GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
    || (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))) // to exit game, press Esc button
    { this.Exit(); }

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
    {
      //insert window from lunch code here...
    }

    // TODO: Add your update logic here
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

I am designing the inventory screen using a window form. However, i have no idea whatsoever on how to load the window form into the Game1 file. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: you could try loading up a windows forms project and copying some of the auto-generated code from that into your xna project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relatively straightforward routes you can go with this that I could recommend:

1. Do everything in XNA. This means all your UI (such as inventory window) would have to be done using XNA techniques. This option is going to give you the best design because, let's be honest, WinForms can be a bit ugly especially when they are forced into something that doesn't look anything like a WinForm
2. Do everything in WinForms. Basically your game would have to be in a WinForm so that all your WinForms can easily communicate through their normal means. The good news is that you can embed an XNA screen inside a WinForm. Basically any XNA level editor tutorial will show you how to do this but [here is one example on codeplex](http://xnawinform.codeplex.com/) and [some sample code from Microsoft's collection of examples](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1). From this you should be able to get everything talking. This approach is less than ideal due to performance reasons and aesthetics, but it should be functional if your game is simple enough.

I would highly recommend option one above but if all else fails option two does work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to design your inventory screen inside your XNA project just like any other visual by creating sprites and capturing the user input in the Update method.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you save yourself the trouble and just draw everything out in XNA. Basically have two classes, one that has all the items, and the other for your inventory. You should also have a List to manage things easier.